# AWS Amplify React Native, GET request error 403 status code

Tags: amazon-web-services, react-native, aws-amplify

I enabled access to unauthenticated identities to do some quick testing before integrating authentication. My configuration code is the following,

```
Amplify.configure({
Auth: {
    identityPoolId: 'us-east-1:example',
    region: 'us-east-1',
    userPoolId: 'us-east-1_example',
    userPoolWebClientId: 'us-east-1_example'
},
API: {
    endpoints: [
        {
            name: "example-name",
            endpoint: "https://example.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/prod/example-path"
        },
    ]
}
});
```

and my GET request code is the following,

```
example() {
const apiName = 'example-name';
const path = '/example-path';

API.get(apiName, path).then(response => {
  console.log(response)
}).catch(error => {
  console.log(error)
})
}
```

I followed everything on GitHub and my API gateway and Lambda functions are working correctly when I run a "test" and through postman. But on react-native it's giving me a 403 status code without any detailed explanation. Does this have to do with accessing using unauthenticated identity? Also, I used "example" in my code to hide my personal information, I typed in everything correctly since I'm not getting any syntax error (identity pool recognizes access every time I run it, but cloudWatch doesn't show any log of gateway access)

Comment: Have you tried using a different package like superagent or axios? I've had this issue with RN, (postman worked fine).

Comment: I'll give it a try! Were you able to work your way around?

Comment: yea, I was using react native fetch blob which was screwing up Fetch. using axios and refacting things (because axios responses look different) it worked.

Comment: @GavinThomas Thanks and have you tried it on RN with authenticated identity (with cognito auth)?

Comment: @GavinThomas I ended up getting it working. I had to get rid of the path name ('example-path') from the endpoint url. It was being duplicated

Comment: Oh good! Thanks for the update!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Endpoint in `Amplify.configure` is the InvokeURL from API Gateway, you just need to include the stage (`/prod` in this case) and not the other routes. The other routes are just the path parameters for API.() calls.